# Automatically remaining columns width is resizing whem I'm resizeing a single column

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

When I'm resizing a single column in a RadGrid all the other columns are resizing automatically and the grid gets compressed. Here is my code in clientsettings:

```
<Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" AllowRowResize="false" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="false" ClipCellContentOnResize="true" EnableRealTimeResize="true" AllowResizeToFit="true" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's preferred on the site that questioners don't include signatures or thanks in questions as it detracts a little bit from the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ResizeGridOnColumnResize property to TRUE, i think